# Why am I getting, "Undefined binding(s) detected when compiling FIRST."?

Tags: javascript, sql, postgresql, knex.js

I  have an app with 3 routes: register, login, and dashboard; with dashboard being a protected route.

Within my dashboard route, I am creating a post request which will retrieve the users information.

In my service file:

```
//Return a user by ID
const getUserById = (id) =>
  knex('users').select('user_name').where({ user_id: id }).first();
```

In my controller file:

```
async function create(req, res, next) {
  try {
    const user = await service.getUserById(req.user);
    res.json(user);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
  }
}
```

I get this error:

> `Undefined binding(s) detected when compiling FIRST. Undefined column(s): [user_id] query: select "user_name" from "users" where "user_id" = ? limit ?`

My table `users` has 4 columns: user_id, user_name, user_email, and user_password.

What is wrong with my service file or controller file?

Answer (score 1):

Looking from code the `req.user` must be undefined.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a user object to the function when it expects an id.

`service.getUserById(req.user)`

But the function signature is:

`const getUserById = (id) => ...`

Comment: That would not give an error about undefined column. But yeah would have been more clear to use name `req.user_id` also in the request parameter.